# Media player crashes the app when back button is pressed in android Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer, fileinputstream

In my app I am playing the audio files from my local storage, while playing the audio if I click on the back button my app gets crashed. I tried applying stop(),release(),reset() and other media player functions.

LogCat:

```
11-30 16:09:09.473 2270-2468/? E/SEC_DRM_PLUGIN_Omafl: OmaPlugin::onOpenDecryptSession(fd)::Drm2IsDrmFileByExtFd::file is NOT DRM by extension
11-30 16:09:09.473 2270-2468/? E/PrGenericPlugin: PrGenericPlugin::onOpenDecryptSession() onCanHandle error
11-30 16:09:09.478 8675-8761/? E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
11-30 16:09:09.478 2271-2271/? E/MediaPlayerService: WFD client is not created 
11-30 16:09:09.478 2271-2271/? E/MediaPlayerService: offset error
11-30 16:09:09.478 8675-8761/? E/MediaPlayer: Unable to create media player
11-30 16:09:09.483 8675-8761/? E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 1
11-30 16:09:09.483 8675-8761/? E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
11-30 16:09:09.483 8675-8761/? E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
11-30 16:09:09.488 2271-8776/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getParameter(133:SEC.mp3.dec, ??(0x7f010008)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
11-30 16:09:21.548 2912-3282/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 9745 [11-30 16:09:21.553]
```

code

```
public class DetailPageFragment extends Fragment implements OnCompletionListener,MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public OnDetailPageLoadListener mListener;
    public Boolean isLoaded = false;
    String idToPass;
    String buttonToPass;
    public int headCellHeight;
    public String headword;
    public String hwdID;
    public String homNum;
    public String senseNum;
    Thread displayThread;
    Handler handler;
    public boolean thesRedirect;
    public boolean sendBack;
    public String imageName;
    ProgressBar pb_detail;
    Tracker t;
    public int scrollYpostion;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "LDOCE6PrefsFile";
    boolean isRedirected;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_detail_page_fragment, null);

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnDetailPageLoadListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
        // Get the Tracker and Initialise it
        t = ((LDOCEApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
                LDOCEApp.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
        t.setScreenName("Word Description Page");
        t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            try {
                imageName = getImageDetailFromDB(headword);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        pb_detail = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pb_detail);
        pb_detail.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.rgb(103, 144, 177), Mode.MULTIPLY);
        final WebView webView = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.wv_headCell);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }
        if (webView != null) {
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(getResources(), getActivity(), this), "JavaScriptInterface");
            webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
            WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
            SharedPreferences fontSizePreferences =  getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            int fontSizeValue = fontSizePreferences.getInt("FONT_VALUE", 0);
            if (fontSizeValue==0)
                webViewSettings.setTextZoom(webViewSettings.getTextZoom()+1);
            if (fontSizeValue==2)
                webViewSettings.setTextZoom(webViewSettings.getTextZoom()+3);
            if (fontSizeValue==4)
                webViewSettings.setTextZoom(webViewSettings.getTextZoom()+7);
            if (fontSizeValue==8)
                webViewSettings.setTextZoom(webViewSettings.getTextZoom()+15);
        }

        // Handler to Update the UI
        handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);

                try {
                    //Update the History Table for current tapped word - ordering the History Table
                    updateHistoryTable(headword,hwdID);
                    //checks whether Detail Page is still in Loading state or not
                    isLoaded = true;
                        if (webView!=null) {
                            String msgToLoad=String.valueOf(msg.obj);
                            if(String.valueOf(msg.obj).contains("&lt;expandHWD/&gt;")){
                                System.out.println("Replace the String");
                                String hwd=headword;
                                if(hwd!=null){
                                    msgToLoad=msgToLoad.replaceAll("&lt;expandHWD/&gt;",hwd+" ");
                                }
                            }
                            //putting the homnum and sense value value
                            if(String.valueOf(msg.obj).contains("replaceHomnum") && !isRedirected){
                                msgToLoad=msgToLoad.replace("replaceHomnum",homNum);
                                isRedirected=true;
                            }
                            if(String.valueOf(msg.obj).contains("replaceSensenum")){
                                msgToLoad=msgToLoad.replace("replaceSensenum",senseNum);
                            }
                            if(String.valueOf(msg.obj).contains("replaceId")){
                                msgToLoad=msgToLoad.replace("replaceId","");
                            }
                            //replaceImageDetails
                            if(String.valueOf(msg.obj).contains("replaceImageDetails")){
                                msgToLoad=msgToLoad.replace("replaceImageDetails",imageName);
                            }
                            if(thesRedirect) {
                                //while Loading - check this ia tablet
                                // If this is tablet -  we have to calculate the Headcell height to show thesaurus content
                                if(Utils.isTablet(getActivity())) {
                                    //check in mastexsltablet -  for a variable ThesNotTapped
                                    if (String.valueOf(msg.obj).contains("ThesNotTapped")) {
                                        msgToLoad = msgToLoad.replace("ThesNotTapped", "ThesTapped");
                                        msgToLoad = msgToLoad.replace("thesHeadwrdId", hwdID);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/www/", msgToLoad, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
                            webView.setScrollY(scrollYpostion);
                        }


                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("DetailPage", "Page didn't load fully and error is " + e.getMessage());

                }

            }
        };

        //Create a separate Thread for content to display in detail page -  This will run in Background Process,without blocking UI
        displayThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String contentsToDisplay = null;
                    contentsToDisplay = displayInfo();
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.obj = contentsToDisplay;
                    if (contentsToDisplay != null) {
                        handler.sendMessage(msg);
                   }
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    Log.v("Content Display Thread", "Thread Exception" + t);
                    mListener.detailPageInterrupted(true);
                }
            }
        });

        displayThread.start();
        mListener.detailPageLoaded(true);
        //Check if it is phone -  navigate to AdditionalInfo -  default for phone headcellheight is 0and thesaurus ItemId is 1004
        if(!Utils.isTablet(getActivity()) && (thesRedirect)){
            navigateToAdditionalInfo(hwdID,0,1004);
            thesRedirect=false;
        }
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            try {
                if (pb_detail != null)
                    pb_detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e("DetailPage", "Page didn't load fully and error is" + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }

    public void playSound(String id, String buttonClicked, Context context) {

            DbConnection dbPath = new DbConnection();
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbPath.getDbConnection();
            boolean isInternetOn = false;
            boolean isPlayed = false;
            if(Utils.isTablet(getContext().getApplicationContext())){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(700);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        // Check if the current existence of DB is not null
            if (db != null && !id.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                String fileName = null;
                Uri url = null;

                //Check for UK English
                if (buttonClicked.equals("uk")) {
                    // Tracking for SlideMenu Button Click
                    t = ((LDOCEApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(LDOCEApp.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
                    // Set the screen as Detail Page
                    t.setScreenName("Word Description Page");
                    // Build and send an Event.
                    t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                            .setCategory("audio_button_action")
                            .setAction("uk_button_click")
                            .setLabel("UKbuttonTapped")
                            .build());
                    // Query to get the records from uksound table
                    String query = String.format("select * from uksound where id=?");
                    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{id});
                    //Check id presents in the table
                    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                        fileName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("filename"));
                    }
                    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState()
                            .equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                        String filePath = File.separator + "sdcard" + File.separator + "Android" + File.separator + "obb" + File.separator + ".media_files_228" + File.separator + "ldoce6_hwd_gb" + File.separator + fileName;
                        try {
                            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                            String entry = null;
                            while ((entry = fis.toString()) != null) {
                                if (!entry.toString().isEmpty()) {
                                    File Mytemp = File.createTempFile("TCL", "mp3", getActivity().getCacheDir());
                                    Mytemp.deleteOnExit();
                                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Mytemp);
                                    for (int c = fis.read(); c != -1; c = fis.read()) {
                                        try {
                                            fos.write(c);
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                                    fos.close();
                                    FileInputStream MyFile = new FileInputStream(Mytemp);

                                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MyFile.getFD());
                                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                                    mediaPlayer.start();
                                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                                    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.unable_to_locate_media_files, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                            fis.close();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        } finally {
                            if (mediaPlayer != null && !mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                                mediaPlayer.stop();
//                                mediaPlayer = null;
                                mediaPlayer.release();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (fileName != null)
                        url = Uri.parse("http://eltapps.pearson.com/ldoce6app/ldoce6_hwd_gb/");
                }

                //Check for US English
                else if (buttonClicked.equals("us")) {
                    t = ((LDOCEApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(LDOCEApp.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
                    // Set the screen as Detail Page
                    t.setScreenName("Word Description Page");
                    // Build and send an Event.
                    t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                            .setCategory("audio_button_action")
                            .setAction("us_button_click")
                            .setLabel("USbuttonTapped")
                            .build());
                    // Query to get the records from ussound table
                    String query = String.format("select * from ussound where id=?");
                    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{id});
                    //Check id presents in the table
                    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                        //Assign the filename
                        fileName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("filename"));
                    }
                    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState()
                            .equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                        String filePath = File.separator + "sdcard" + File.separator + "Android" + File.separator + "obb" + File.separator + ".media_files_228" + File.separator + "ldoce6_hwd_us" + File.separator + fileName;
                        try {
                            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                            String zipFileName = "convertMp3ToDb" + File.separator + "ldoce6_hwd_us" + File.separator + fileName;
                            String entry = null;
                            while ((entry = fis.toString()) != null) {
                                if (!entry.toString().isEmpty()) {
                                    File Mytemp = File.createTempFile("TCL", "mp3", getActivity().getCacheDir());
                                    Mytemp.deleteOnExit();
                                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Mytemp);
                                    for (int c = fis.read(); c != -1; c = fis.read()) {
                                        try {
                                            fos.write(c);
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                                    fos.close();
                                    FileInputStream MyFile = new FileInputStream(Mytemp);
                                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MyFile.getFD());
                                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                                    mediaPlayer.start();
                                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                                    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.unable_to_locate_media_files, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                            fis.close();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        } finally {
                            if (mediaPlayer != null && !mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                                mediaPlayer.stop();
//                                mediaPlayer = null;
                                mediaPlayer.release();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (fileName != null)
                        url = Uri.parse("http://eltapps.pearson.com/ldoce6app/ldoce6_hwd_us/");
                } else if (buttonClicked.equals("example")) {
                    //fetch the filename from exampleSound table from database
                    String query = String.format("select * from exasound where id=?");
                    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{id});
                    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                        fileName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("filename"));
                    }

                    if (fileName != null)
                        url = Uri.parse("http://eltapps.pearson.com/ldoce6app/ldoce6_exa_pron/");
//                        Toast.makeText(context,R.string.sorry_audio_is_not_available,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.unable_to_locate_media_files, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                /*Get the file path url and convert to string
                    * Concatenate the filename with the file path url
                    * Initialise the mediaPlayer and assign the data source with the file path url*/
                if (url != null) {
                    String filePath = url.toString();
                    filePath = filePath.concat(fileName);
                    idToPass = id;
                    buttonToPass = buttonClicked;
                    //Call for media player
                    playerStart(filePath);
                } else {
                    callToWebView(id, buttonClicked);
                }

                // Close the DB Connection
                db.close();
            } else {
                callToWebView(id, buttonClicked);
            }

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        callToWebView();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        /*Stop the loader and make the US or UK button back to normal state
        call the restoreSoundButtonState in main.js */
        Log.v("Completed", "Audio played successfully");
        //Call for webView without params
        callToWebView();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }

    //Method to call webView to update the button state
    public void callToWebView(String idToPass, String buttonToPass) {
        //Call to webView
        final WebView webview = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.wv_headCell);
        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            //Add idToPass and buttonToPass to json object
            jsonObject.put("id", idToPass);
            jsonObject.put("btn", buttonToPass);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Run in a separate thread
        if (webview != null)
            webview.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Call the jQuery function from java code with the jsonObject
                    webview.loadUrl("javascript:restoreSoundButtonState(" + jsonObject.toString() + ")");
                }
            });
    }

    //function is used to scroll to a particular homnum entry in detail page
    public void navigateToEntryWithHomnum() {
        WebView webview = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.wv_headCell);
        if (webview != null) {
            String function = "javascript:navigateToHomnumOrSense('" + homNum + "')";
            webview.loadUrl(function);
        }
    }

    //Media player call
    private void playerStart(String filePath) {
        //Make audio manager in stream music
        if (mediaPlayer == null)
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        try {
            //Set url to data source
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
            //Prepare the player
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            //Play the audio
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Handle scenarios for back, home button pressed and fragment cancelled
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            callToWebView();
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer = null;
        if (displayThread.isAlive()) {
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(displayThread);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //Remove any additional info if open for tab
        if(Utils.isTablet(getActivity())) {
            removeDummyCellAndCloseAdditionalInfo();
        }
        // Sending Hit to GA as Start of new Activity
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getActivity()).reportActivityStart(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        // Sending Hit to GA as End of Activity
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getActivity()).reportActivityStop(getActivity());
        WebView webview = (WebView)getActivity() .findViewById(R.id.wv_headCell);
        if (webview!=null)
            scrollYpostion = webview.getScrollY();

    }

    /**
     * performs search or copy
     * It will execute the funtion in JavaScript and JSInterface will handle the action
     * @param action action to be performed
     */
    public void performSearchOrCopy(String action)

    {
        WebView webview = (WebView)getActivity() .findViewById(R.id.wv_headCell);
            // to call the jQuery function from java code
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            jsonArray.put(action);
            if(webview!=null)
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:getSelectedString(" + jsonArray.toString() + ")");
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Back button click crashes the app while media player playing the audio files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864920/back-button-click-crashes-the-app-while-media-player-playing-the-audio-files)

Comment: solution for crash?

Comment: no solution. You just can't re-ask questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
}
```

Comment: In fragment is it possible?

Comment: Yes, a fragment is set on an `Activity`, `onBackPressed()` is called when you click back button of the phone. Since you are overriding the function, this will work. Please upvote if this works. :)

Comment: Overrride method ask for an interface to implement it

Comment: Can you edit your question with the entire code? Is you Fragment implementing any interface?

Comment: I posted my code some functions may be missing due to character restrictions

Comment: Instead of `onBackPressed()` you can use stop the mediaplayer in the `onPause()' of the Fragment

Comment: Already onPause is there in my code but facing the same issue

Comment: First stop the mediaplayer and then call `callToWebView()`

Comment: Use my code in Activity which is calling this Fragment. Use the Fragment object in the activity to control the Fragment's mediaplayer

Answer (score 0):

Override the onBackPressed() method in your activity.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(media player is playing) {
        // then stop it
      }
        super.onBackPressed();

}
```

Comment: In fragment onbackpressed override method is not applicable

Answer (score 0):

Change your onPause() to release all the MediaPlayer Objects instead of trying to restart song currently playing.

`public void onPause()
{`

```
super.onPause();

song.release();
song1.release();
//and so on
```

}`

Comment: tried mediaplayer.release(); not working still facing same issue

Comment: @MahalakshmiSaravanan use realse method() in callback methods